# Oops. conf/routes or conf/application.conf missing.?

Tags: java, playframework

I followed the "[Learn](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/guide1)" on play official site.
I am using window 7+Chrome.

```
  D:\tester\play>dir
 Volume in drive D is APPLIS
 Volume Serial Number is 9037-F7BD

 Directory of D:\tester\play

07/15/2011  10:38 PM    <DIR>          .
07/15/2011  10:38 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/15/2011  11:00 AM             1,810 COPYING
07/15/2011  10:33 PM    <DIR>          documentation
07/15/2011  10:34 PM    <DIR>          framework
07/15/2011  10:35 PM    <DIR>          modules
06/06/2011  08:10 PM             5,858 play
06/06/2011  08:10 PM                50 play.bat
07/15/2011  10:35 PM    <DIR>          python
06/06/2011  08:10 PM             1,834 README.textile
07/15/2011  10:35 PM    <DIR>          resources
07/15/2011  10:33 PM    <DIR>          samples-and-tests
07/15/2011  10:35 PM    <DIR>          support
07/15/2011  10:53 PM    <DIR>          yabe
               4 File(s)          9,552 bytes
              10 Dir(s)  100,984,504,320 bytes free

D:\tester\play>play run
~        _            _
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/
~
~ play! 1.2.2, http://www.playframework.org
~
~ Oops. conf/routes or conf/application.conf missing.
~ D:\tester\play does not seem to host a valid application.
~


D:\tester\play>play run yabe
~        _            _
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/
~
~ play! 1.2.2, http://www.playframework.org
~
~ Ctrl+C to stop
~
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
23:09:24,780 INFO  ~ Starting D:\tester\play\yabe
23:09:31,483 WARN  ~ You're running Play! in DEV mode
23:09:32,615 ERROR ~ Could not bind on port 9000
```

Now I am waiting to solve this problems so I Can continue to learn Play the next steps.

I try to Google But I did not got the good answer for my case.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Oops. conf/routes or conf/application.conf missing` is misleading you, this is only happening because you tried to start a Play application without specifying an application to run. Just typing `play run` will cause an error because there is no application to run in the current directory. Instead, you just need to type `play run yabe`.

Your second error, `Unable to bind to port 9000` usually means there is something already running on that port.

The easiest thing to do is to change the port that Play is running on and restart the server.

To do this, just open the yabe/app/conf/application.conf file, and change this line

```
# http.port=9000
```

to

```
http.port=9001
```

And keep incrementing the number until you find a free port. If you get past 9005, you may be better of doing a port scan to see which ports are in use, rather than going on for ever!